# How to force haproxy http to close connection with client?

Tags: iptables, haproxy

I have a backend that performs some analysis of JSON data and if client's data is invalid I have to ban client. My backend use ipsets and iptables rule, but in order to make these rules work I must first kill connection, otherwise attacker can continue to abuse backend. Please tell me is it possible to force haproxy to kill connection with client or how to adjust my firewall rules to take effect on established connections.

Rule:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set abusers src -p TCP --match multiport --dports 8080 -j REJECT
```

And options in haproxy in order to get real ip:

```
reqidel ^X-Forwarded-For:.*
option forwardfor
```

My only solution at this moment is to use "option forceclose".

Comment: Are you opposed to using forceclose?

Comment: Yes, I am using it already. Still not a solution for me, I'd like to control it. If it's not possible, okay, let it foreclose.